# Make foreach with nested-ifs more compact and readable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Looking for C# syntax to make the following code more elegant, compact and readable. The foreach with the multiple if's take up too much space and look too ugly. I'm thinking LINQ syntax maybe?

(srSys and desSys are strings, and srFl and desFl are ints. The final version will have better variable naming)

```
public static warMod Gen ( List<AtMap> atMaps ) {

        List<AtMap> atMapList = new List<AtMap>();

        foreach(var a in atMaps)
        {
            AtMap atMap = new AtMap();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.srSys))
            {
                atMap.srSys = a.srSys;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.desSys))
            {
                atMap.desSys = a.desSys;
            }

            if (a.srFl != null)
            {
                atMap.srFl = a.srFl;
            }

            if (a.desFl != null)
            {
                atMap.desFl = a.desFl;
            }

            atMapList.Add(atMap);
        }
        return new warMod {AtMapArr = atMapList}
    }
```

Comment: " srFl and desFl are ints" is … not necessary a true statement... you may want to doublecheck your code to confirm which way post misinforms readers.

Comment: This should probably be migrated to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What is the default value of `AtMap.srSys` and `AtMap.desSys`?

Comment: Any reason you cannot directly return `AtMaps` ? Since `AtMaps` and `AtMapsList` are both of the same `List<AtMap>` type

Answer (score 1):

You could simply put the if's hidden away forever inside of the AtMap class.

```
public static warMod Gen(List<AtMap> atMaps)
{
    List<AtMap> atMapList = new List<AtMap>();
    foreach (var a in atMaps)
        atMapList.Add(new AtMap(a));

    return new warMod { AtMapArr = atMapList };
}

public class AtMap
{
    public AtMap(AtMap a)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.srSys))
            srSys = a.srSys;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.desSys))
            desSys = a.desSys;
        if (a.srFl != null)
            srFl = a.srFl;
        if (a.desFl != null)
            desFl = a.desFl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Given that the overall logic of the function seems to just take an `List<AtMap>` type named `AtMaps` and make another `List<AtMap>` type named `AtMapsList>`. The function can simply be `return new warMod {AtMapArr = atMaps};`. However, the constructor can still be used at the part where `AtMaps` is made

```
// Use of constructor to initialize your class (AtMap.cs)
public class AtMap {
    public string srSys, desSys;
    public int? srFl, desFl;
    public AtMap(string srSys, string desSys, int? srFl, int? desFl) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.srSys)) {
            this.srSys = a.srSys;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.desSys)) {
            this.desSys = a.desSys;
        }
        if (a.srFl != null) {
            this.srFl = a.srFl;
        }
        if (a.desFl != null) {
            this.desFl = a.desFl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is a possible starting point the code totally misses the point of not updating values if parameter is not set...

Comment: Put null check on your constructor

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your class AtMap fields: srSys and desSys will be empty, srFl and desFl (for example: int) will be 0.
I think it can be like this:

```
public class AtMap 
{
    public string srSys {get; set;}
    public string desSys {get; set;}
    public int srFl {get; set;}
    public int desFl {get; set;}
}

public static warMod Gen(List<AtMap> atMaps)
{
    var atMapList = new List<AtMap>();

    foreach (var a in atMaps)
    {
        var atMap = new AtMap
        {
            srSys = a.srSys,
            desSys = a.desSys,
            srFl = a.srFl ?? default(int),
            desFl = a.desFl ?? default(int)
        };

        atMapList.Add(atMap);
    }
    return new warMod { AtMapArr = atMapList };
}
```